# Como pódria quitar el texto que aparece por defecto al subir un archivo

Tags: html

[[image: Imagen de ejemplo1]

En la imagen de ejemplo anterior creo que ya se ve el problema con claridad. Se superpone el texto de seleccionar archivo, no es un texto mio, viene definido ya. como puedo hacer para que no se ponga por encima el texto de seleccionar archivo?

Este es el código:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3"><!--left col-->
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
                        <h6>Cambia tu foto de perfil...</h6>
                        <input type="file" class="text-center center-block file-upload">
                      </div><br>
                        </div><!--/col-3-->
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" style="margin-left:1rem">Editar perfil</a></li>
                              </ul>
                          <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                <hr>
                                  <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre:</h4></label>

                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos:</h4></label>

                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico:</h4></label>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="locate"><h4>Localidad</h4></label>
                        
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal:</h4></label>
                                    
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                </form>
                              <hr>
                             </div><!--/tab-pane-->
                             <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                               <h2></h2>
                               <hr>
                                  <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" title="enter your first name if any.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">

                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Introduce tus dos apellidos" title="enter your last name if any.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">

                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico</h4></label>
                                              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@email.com" title="enter your email.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="email"><h4>Localidad</h4></label>
                                              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Introduce tu localidad" title="enter a location">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal</h4></label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" placeholder="Introduce tu código postal" title="enter a location">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                              <label for="password"><h4>Contraseña</h4></label>
                                              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña" title="enter your password.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <label for="password2"><h4>Repite la contraseña</h4></label>
                                              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Introduce la contraseña anterior" title="enter your password2.">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                           <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                <br>
                                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Guardar</button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Restablecer</button>
                                            </div>
                                      </div>
                                </form>
                             </div><!--/tab-pane-->
                             </div><!--/tab-pane-->
                          </div><!--/tab-content-->
                        </div><!--/col-9-->
                    </div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: Para darte una solución fiel a tu problema... ¿Podrías añadir el **HTML** también donde construyes el apartado de nombre, apellidos, etc? Ya que el problema atañe a la interacción entre ambas secciones no estaría de más contar con las dos. Puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta.

Comment: Listo!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: El único camino para conseguir lo que quieres es a través de un "custom input". Si tan solo quieres hacerlo con HTML y CSS perderías usabilidad al no poder mostrar el nombre del fichero seleccionado. En caso de querer mostrarlo necesitarías hacer uso de Javascript.

Comment: Como se haria en javascript, simplemente con que el texto me saliera debajo de seleccionar archivo ya estaria.

Comment: El problema es que el texto del archivo seleccionado es renderizado por el navegador. Nosotros no podemos afectarlo con CSS. Además, cada navegador lo renderiza a su manera, por lo que puede mostrarse diferente dependiendo de este. Una estrategia muy común para evitar estos es cambiar este tipo de inputs por unos personalizados para poder controlar perfectamente sus estilos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más sencilla es hacerte un "input custom" a través de **HTML** y **CSS**. En mi caso, envolví el `<input type="file">` en un `<label>` y a este le di aspecto de botón, ocultando el input "real".

**Haciendo uso de HTML y CSS**

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><!--left col-->
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
    <h6>Cambia tu foto de perfil...</h6>
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
      <input type="file"/>
      Subir archivo
    </label>
  </div><br>
    </div><!--/col-3-->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" style="margin-left:1rem">Editar perfil</a></li>
          </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <hr>
              <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre:</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos:</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico:</h4></label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="locate"><h4>Localidad</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal:</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
          <hr>
         </div><!--/tab-pane-->
         <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
           <h2></h2>
           <hr>
              <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre</h4></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" title="enter your first name if any.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">

                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos</h4></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Introduce tus dos apellidos" title="enter your last name if any.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">

                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico</h4></label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@email.com" title="enter your email.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="email"><h4>Localidad</h4></label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Introduce tu localidad" title="enter a location">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal</h4></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" placeholder="Introduce tu código postal" title="enter a location">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="password"><h4>Contraseña</h4></label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña" title="enter your password.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="password2"><h4>Repite la contraseña</h4></label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Introduce la contraseña anterior" title="enter your password2.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <br>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Restablecer</button>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
         </div><!--/tab-pane-->
         </div><!--/tab-pane-->
      </div><!--/tab-content-->
    </div><!--/col-9-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

**Haciendo uso de HTML, CSS y JS (JQuery)**

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
     let nombre_fichero = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();

     $('.custom-file-upload').next('span').html(nombre_fichero);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><!--left col-->
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
    <h6>Cambia tu foto de perfil...</h6>
    <label class="custom-file-upload">
      <input type="file"/>
      Subir archivo
    </label>
    <span>Ningún fichero seleccionado</span>
  </div><br>
    </div><!--/col-3-->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" style="margin-left:1rem">Editar perfil</a></li>
          </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <hr>
              <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre:</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos:</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico:</h4></label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="locate"><h4>Localidad</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal:</h4></label>

                      </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
          <hr>
         </div><!--/tab-pane-->
         <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
           <h2></h2>
           <hr>
              <form class="form" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="first_name"><h4>Nombre</h4></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre" title="enter your first name if any.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">

                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="last_name"><h4>Apellidos</h4></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Introduce tus dos apellidos" title="enter your last name if any.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">

                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="email"><h4>Correo electrónico</h4></label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@email.com" title="enter your email.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="email"><h4>Localidad</h4></label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Introduce tu localidad" title="enter a location">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="cp"><h4>Código postal</h4></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cp" placeholder="Introduce tu código postal" title="enter a location">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <label for="password"><h4>Contraseña</h4></label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña" title="enter your password.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="password2"><h4>Repite la contraseña</h4></label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Introduce la contraseña anterior" title="enter your password2.">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <br>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Restablecer</button>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
         </div><!--/tab-pane-->
         </div><!--/tab-pane-->
      </div><!--/tab-content-->
    </div><!--/col-9-->
</div><!--/row-->
```